# Создать свой класс

Tags: c#

Пожалуйста, приведите пример как создать новый тип (класс) age, наследовать его от int, ограничить от 0 до 100. Спасибо.

Comment: никак, int - Это структура, а у структур нет наследования

Comment: можете сделать класс в котором будет поле типа int и для конструктора/сеттера этого поля поставить ограничение, что поле может быть только от 0 до 100

Comment: Друзья, когда ставите минусы, ну хоть что-то напишите, не поленитесь прокомментировать.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, подсказка к стрелочке, по нажатии которой ставится минус: _Вопрос не отражает стремления разобраться; он непонятен или не несёт пользы_

Comment: Мне не нужна помощь в решении проблемы. Мне было интересно ,возможно ли так сделать.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, тогда стоило переформулировать вопрос

Comment: Уже нет смысла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чем не устраивает такой вариант:

```
class Number
{
    int x
    {
        get { return x; }
        set
        {
            if ((value > 100) || (value < 0))
                throw new ArgumentException();
            else
                x = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: например тем, что не выполняется пункт: _наследовать его от int_

Comment: `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`  был бы более актуальным.

Comment: class Number : int : вот так Вам студия скажет следующее:
'Number': не может быть производным от запечатанного типа "int".
Вам уже писали - от него нельзя наследоваться

Comment: Возможно Вы правы, teran. Не задумывался нед этим.

Comment: :-D не мне писали, а я писал :-D

Comment: Извините, не обратил внимания, что это Вы и есть.

Comment: Ответ нормальный, но Grundy дал ответ в комментарии.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, а это точно вся задача? Больше похоже, что формулировка либо не полная, либо не точная

Comment: Хотел свой уникальный тип для хранения возраста, не больше. Стало интересно, можно ли наследовать от Int и т.д.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов можно сделать enum со 100 значениями :)

Comment: ))) Хороший юмор.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов, это в принципе единственный способ _"наследоваться"_ от чисел

Comment: @Grundy угу, и притом только от целых =)

Comment: Есть ещё вариант: Заходите сюда https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,225942ed7b7a3252  это реализация структуры Int32 от МС. Копируете то что вам нужно, и делаете свой класс, например MyInt32. А потом спокойно наследуетесь от него. Извращение конечно, но вашу задачу решает.